# Clone INPUT element just after his equal an inside the right DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
{% for entity in items %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ entity.getLabel|lower }}" id="{{ entity.getLabel|lower ~ "_choice" }}" value="{{ entity.getId }}" /> {{ entity.getLabel }}
{% endfor %}

{% for entity in items %}
    <div id="{{ entity.getLabel|lower ~ "_choice_" ~ entity.getId }}" style="display: none">
        <button type="button" class="{{ entity.getLabel|lower }}">Adicionar {{ entity.getLabel|lower }}</button>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

<button type="button" class="create-variation" id="create-variation" style="display: none">{{'Crear variaciones'|trans}}</button>

<section id="variations_holder" style="display: none"></section>
```

And this is how it looks when it's rendered:

```
    <div style="" id="talla_choice_24">
        <span>Talla<input placeholder="Talla" value="" data-id="talla_24" name="input_talla[]"></span>
        <br>
        <button class="talla" type="button">Adicionar talla</button>
    </div>
    <div style="" id="color_choice_25">
        <span>Color<input placeholder="Color" value="" data-id="color_25" name="input_color[]"></span>
        <br>
        <button class="color" type="button">Adicionar color</button>
    </div>
```

For first time I create a input as follow:

```
$('#choices').on("change", ":checkbox", function(e) {
    var theName = $(this).attr('name');
    var theID = $(this).attr('value');
    var hasChecked = $(this).is('checked').length;
    var input = "";

    input = '<span>' + capitalize(theName) + '<input name="input_' + theName + '[]" data-id="' + theName + '_' + theID + '" value="" placeholder="' + capitalize(theName) + '" /></span><br/>';

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':button').before(input);
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).show();
    } else {
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).find(':not(button)').remove();
        $("#" + theName + '_choice_' + theID).hide();
    }
});
```

This code works right, what I'm needing now is to clone each input element based on the button I made click. For example, less said I click the button "button#talla" then I should clone the element:

```
<span>Talla<input placeholder="Talla" value="" data-id="talla_24" name="input_talla[]"></span><br>
```

In the other hand if I click "button#color" then what I should clone is:

```
<span>Color<input placeholder="Color" value="" data-id="color_25" name="input_color[]"></span><br>
```

Of course the code should work with first template approach not with generated code since it's dynamically. I'm working on this:

```
$("#choices").on("click", ":button", function(e) {
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    var theID = $(this).attr('value');
    $("#" + class_name + "_choice span:last").clone().attr("id", theID).before("button." + class_name);
});
```

But doesn't work since it not clones and does anything, can any give me a hand on this?

**PS:** There are some Twig tags and values but forget about them since they set values correctly

Comment: The `$("#" + class_name + "_choice")` selector doesn't match your element I presume. `console.log` the selector and it will become apparent…

Comment: @Bergi, yes I know that already, what I need to do and ask for is help about getting the selector to work

Comment: So what exactly does `class_name` give? I cannot find the buttons in your markup.

Comment: @Bergi buttons are inside `div#talla_choice_24` and `div#color_choice_25`, Right now `class_name`  is taking the button class but I tough is useless in this scenario since what I need to get is the class of the parent DIV in order to clone the latest input on it, is the typically function to add new elements at the end and it's easy when you know elements names or id's but in this case is dynamically since I don't know how the name's or id's will be rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I need to get is the class of the parent DIV in order to clone the latest input on it

No, actually you don't even need this. You just need to access the parent div, regardless of its class - use the [`parent` traversal method](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) on the button that was clicked:

```
$("#choices").on("click", ":button", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().find("span:last").clone().insertBefore(this);
});
```

Btw, the button has no value and the spans or inputs no id so I'm not sure what you tried to do with `theID`.

Comment: Nice, I fix the problem by using this `$("#choices").on("click", "button", function(e) {
        $(this).prevAll("span:last").clone().insertBefore($(this));
    });`

Comment: Yeah, the sibling traversal methods would be the other option :-) I had `.prev().prev()` in mind, but thought that relying on the `<br>` would be too inaccurate.